# Wireless device not recognized on Lenovo t420s after Windows 7 reinstall

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, thinkpad

I have recently replaced a Windows 7 Ultimate with Windows 7 Enterprise by 1) creating a backup using "Windows easy transfer", 2) installing Enterprise, and 3) recovering the backup.

Now, the wireless device does not appear in the Device Manager or under Network Connections, and the wifi light does not light up (the bluetooth one does, indicating that the switch is on).

The device is an Intel Centrino Advanced N 6205. So I downloaded the driver from Lenovo and used the device manager to install driver updates.

I also have Ubuntu installed as dual-boot and it has no problem recognizing the card (+1 @ubuntu).

How can I get Windows to recognize the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Install ThinkVantage System Update Software](http://support.lenovo.com/en_IN/downloads/detail.page?LegacyDocID=TVSU-UPDATE), get all your updates the easy way, you can pick and choose what gets installed.

EDIT: You need at least one network adapter driver installed so the System Update software can connect to the internet to get the rest of the updates.

.

Comment: thanks. I figured it had to be easier than identifying the hardware and installing specific drivers one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Because the device is not recognized, Windows will not know to search either the internet or the computer for the driver during Windows Update or by manually updating the drivers in the Device manager, even if the driver has been downloaded.

For this particular case, download *and* install the [Intel Wireless LAN (bg, abg, abgn) driver](http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles/8aw215ww.exe)

More details and the download can be found at [this support.lenovo page](http://support.lenovo.com/en_CH/downloads/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-77063)